# Instantiating 2D array

Tags: java, arrays

I want to make 2d array and to parse it later :

```
String[][] position  = new String[3][3]; 
    position = [{id:10, x:10, y:20}, {id:5, x:30, y:40}, {id:2, x:2, y:7},];
```

and

```
String[][] position  = [
    {id:10, x:10, y:20}, 
    {id:5, x:30, y:40},
    {id:2, x:2, y:7},
    ];
```

but none of those two seam to work..

Any suggestions on what am I doing wrong?

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You could do this using a 2d array, but I think it would be better to make an object with fields `id`, `x`, and `y`.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis If it was int array then you would be right, but my problem was that it was a string and I forgot " ". And thanks for taking your time to review my 6 months old post and mark it as already answered I really appreciate it.

Comment: Well yeah I see you have a lot of positive marks you should see that its String array and it need " "... I am learning slowly and trying to get some positive marks here but sometimes I get downvotes for no reasons. Like today I post a correct response and I get negative points I just don't understand it

Comment: It says "The answer is not useful" and op said it is and thanked me for helping him out... I never said there is no reason to vote but why I have -1 on something that OP found useful? My guess is someone being mean.

Comment: And there are also lot of new users who post something and then don't reply on answers and don't upvote or downvote answers, example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47005898/multiple-random-numbers/47005921#47005921 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46993023/getting-substring-out-of-string-and-an-integer-and-creating-new-word-within-the/46993156#46993156 
And i started helping like only 2-3 days ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First String is not int, String should be between `""`, your assign should be like this :

```
String[][] position  = 
                 {{"id:10", "x:10", "y:20"}, {"id:5", "x:30", "y:40"}, {"2", "2", "7"}};
```

If you mean array of int, your array should look like this :

```
int[][] position  = {{10, 10, 20}, {5, 30, 40}, {2, 2, 7}};
```

Comment: Fixed it thanks... didn't see { } that was the problem.

Answer (score 3):

you can do a constants initialization of the array

How?:

replace the **[ ]** with **{ }** and place on it **VALID STRINGS** since that is what your array is holding

```
String[][] position  = {  {"id:10", "x:10", "y:20"}, 
{"id:5", "x:30", "y:40"},
{"id:2", "x:2", "y:7"} };
```

note that this is a special init is only valid when done with the declaration... meaning that following is invalid:

```
String[][] position;
position  = {  {"id:10", "x:10", "y:20"},     {"id:5", "x:30", "y:40"},
{"id:2", "x:2", "y:7"} };
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
int[][] multi = new int[3][3];
```

Or

```
int[] twoDimIntArray[] = new int[3][3];
```

this is equivalent to

```
int[][] multi = new int[][]{
  { 0, 0, 0 },
  { 0, 0, 0 },
  { 0, 0, 0 },
  { 0, 0, 0 },
  { 0, 0, 0 }
};
```

After initializing, you can enter your values