# getting substring out of string and an integer, and creating new word within the integer parameters

Tags: java

for my java class, I need to make a method that gets a word out of a string that fits within  a parameter

ex:"the walking dead", 3 returns "the."

Comment: Can you write some tries you did, please?

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/ http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ also please read https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems

Comment: This is rather poorly formulated. I don't think that this is the original wording for the exercise.

Answer (score 0):

```
String word = "the walking dead";
String result = word.substring(0, 3);
```

Try that