# Multiple Random Numbers

Tags: c#, random

Hey how can i make the col1 random on each vehicle created it can be same on some but not all of them can have the same color.

```
Random r = new Random();

col1 = r.Next(0, 159);

CreateVehicle(-614, -352, 34,col1, col2, 0);
CreateVehicle(-614, -352, 34,col1, col2, 0);
CreateVehicle(-614, -352, 34,col1, col2, 0);
CreateVehicle(-614, -352, 34,col1, col2, 0);
CreateVehicle(-614, -352, 34,col1, col2, 0);
CreateVehicle(-614, -352, 34,col1, col2, 0);
CreateVehicle(-614, -352, 34,col1, col2, 0);
CreateVehicle(-614, -352, 34,col1, col2, 0);
CreateVehicle(-614, -352, 34,col1, col2, 0);
CreateVehicle(-614, -352, 34,col1, col2, 0);
```

Comment: aaand what language is this?

Comment: is it c#? looks so.

Comment: @Chris I would guess C#, in which case you're using System.Random wrong and your code will eventually lead to either "not random at all" numbers or plain zeroes, depending on how you use it.

Answer (score 0):

you need to put r.next inside all of them because what you do is assign a value to col1 and its same in every vehicle.

Comment: CreateVehicle(-614, -352, 34,r.nextInt(159), col2, 0);

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `col1 = r.Next(0, 159);` before creating each vehicle. One easy way would be to put that code inside a loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    col1 = r.Next(0, 159);
    CreateVehicle(-614, -352, 34, col1, col2, 0);
}
```